# syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: bash, shell-script

I tried changing some things in my code and still it doesn't work :S

```
#!/bin/bash 



function auto_net() {
    welcome
}

function welcome() {    
    echo "Will your net include a server?"
    read choice 
    if [ $choice -eq "Yes" ]; then
        interface Server;   
    elif [ $choice -eq "No" ];
    then
        interface Default;
    fi
}

function user_input() {
    declare -a devices=("${!1}")
    for((i=1; i <= $2; ++i)); do
         device=$3
         device="$device$i"
         devices+=("$device")   
    done
    for i in ${devices[@]}; do
        echo $i
    done
}

function interface() {
    if[ "$1" -eq "Server" ];
    then
        set_up Server;
        set_up Router;
        set_up Switch;
        set_up Host;
    elif[ "$1" -eq "Default" ]; then
        set_up Router;
        set_up Switch;
        set_up Host;
    fi
}

function set_up (){
    local routers=()
    local hosts=()      
    local switches=()
    if [ "$1" -eq  "Router" ];
    then    
        echo "How many routers are you going to configure?"
        read router_number
        user_input routers[@] router_number R 
    elif [ "$1" -eq "Switch" ];
    then
        echo "How many switches are there?"
        read switch_number
        user_input switches[@] switch_number S 

       elif [ $1 -eq "Host" ];
       then
            echo "How many hosts per switch? Type it in order"
        read host_number
        user_input hosts[@] host_number H
       fi 
}

auto_net
echo $?
```

Comment: Try https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 5):

You are missing some spaces.

- `if[ "$1" -eq "Server" ];`
- `elif[ "$1" -eq "Default" ]; then`

These should be a space after the keywords `if` and `elif`.

- `for((i=1; i <= $2; ++i)); do`

This (missing space after `for`) is not strictly an error, but should be fixed for consistency with the rest of the code.

You are also using `-eq` throughout for string comparisons.  To compare strings, use `=` (`-eq` compares integers):

```
if [ $choice = "Yes" ]; then
```

I'm also not sure what you would want this to do:

```
user_input routers[@] router_number R
```

You may want

```
routers=( $(user_input "$router_number" R) )
```

or something similar (and modify your `user_input` function to match that).

You should also double quote the variable expansions. See "[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)" as to why.

Paste your script into ShellCheck to get a fuller list of possible problems: https://www.shellcheck.net/

As a general tip, you may want to test run your script as you develop it, just to make sure that what you've just written actually works. As opposed to writing a complete script before testing it at all.

Another tip to avoid lengthy `if`-`then`-`elif` bits is to use `case ... esac`:

```
case "$1" in
    Router)
        echo 'How many routers?'
        read router_number
        # etc.
        ;;
    Switch)
        # stuff for switches
        ;;
    Host)
        # stuff for hosts
        ;;
    *)
        echo 'Something is wrong' >&1
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

This also allows for easy pattern matching.  `R*)` in a "case label" will match `Router` and any other string that starts with `R`. `R*|H*)` would match any string that starts with either `R` or `H`, etc.

Comment: @Kuslananda +1 Your explanations are exemplary.

Comment: `for((i=1; i <= $2; ++i)); do` would be OK even if not "canonical", `(` can act as a token delimiter (like `<`, `;` or `|` but contrary to `[` or `{` for instance). So things like `if(cmd)` or `while<foo cmd` should work.